# How to create a custom grouped / hashed PLINQ partitioner or parallel query

Tags: c#, .net-core, plinq

I am trying to process a list of file paths in parallel using PLINQ.
I have to process all files with the same name, excluding extension, in the same thread, as that thread may be renaming file extensions, causing issues if done from different threads at the same time.

From the docs it looks like a Hash based partition can be created by using e.g. GroupBy(), or I need to create a custom Partition. I could not find usable examples of either, at least not what I understood and could get to work.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-dynamic-partitions
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/partitioning-in-plinq/
https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/parallel-linq-2-partitioning

I'd like to ask advice on how to use e.g. GroupBy(), or is there a pre-existing hash partition scheme where I can just provide the hash key to a function?

Example code:

```cs
// All files with the same path minus extension must be processed together
var fileList = new List<string>()
{
    "/path1/file1.ext",
    "/path1/file2.ext",
    "/path2/file1.avi",
    "/path1/file1.mkv",
    "/path1/file3.avi",
    "/path1/file1.avi",
    "/path2/file3.mkv",
    "/path1/file2.mkv"
};

// Group files by path ignoring extensions
var pathDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
fileList.ForEach(path => {
    string normalPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
    if (pathDictionary.TryGetValue(normalPath, out var pathList))
    {
        pathList.Add(path);
    }
    else
    {
        pathDictionary.Add(normalPath, new List<string> { path });
    }
});

// HOWTO: Skip the grouping and use GroupBy() or a native hash iterator?

// Process groups in parallel
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(pathDictionary, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
partitioner.AsParallel()
    .ForAll(keyPair =>
    {
        keyPair.Value.ForEach(fileName => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}, Path: {fileName}");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Related: [Dynamically processing a concurrent collection in parallel by group but serially within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000722/dynamically-processing-a-concurrent-collection-in-parallel-by-group-but-serially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are close at solving your problem. The `GroupBy` operator will emit groups of paths that have the same key. So you just have to do a `foreach` loop inside the `ForAll` lambda, and process the paths that have the same key one by one:

```
pathList
    .GroupBy(path => Path.ChangeExtension(path, ""), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(g =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}, Key: {g.Key}");
        foreach (string path in g)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}, Path: {path}");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });
```

As you can see the `GroupBy` can be placed before or after the `AsParallel`. It doesn't make much of a difference, because retrieving the key of each path is not CPU intensive. So doing it sequentially should not be any slower than doing it in parallel.

Comment: Ok, great!  
Followup, I tested with no Partitioner using the list directly, a dynamic Partitioner(pathList, true), and my previous single item partitioner Partitioner.Create(fileList, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering).  
Using the GroupBy() it does appear to no longer require the NoBuffering option, but my sample size is small, could you confirm if a singe thread will get multiple Groups queued or only fed a group at a time?  
The problem is when a thread gets more than one job queued, runs for hours, and other threads sit idle while they could have processed that queued workload.

Comment: @PieterV this looks like a different question, and I don't have enough info to answer it in a comment. I would suggest to experiment with this answer, and if it gives you any problems then you could come up a new question.