# Lock code by string name with parallelism in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, semaphore, parallel.foreach

I have the following code:

```
string[] arr = ["A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"];

var options = new ParallelOptions() { 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 
};

Parallel.ForEach(arr, options , res =>
{
    // No double res with the same name is allowed
    // Code with res
});
```

I want the code in the parallel loop to be able to execute **A** and **B** at the same time and wait for the first **B** to finish in order to move to the next **B**.

In other word, it is not allowed to run the code on the same **res** at the same time.

With named semaphore, if I want to create a semaphore at runtime, it can't be static.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Create a dictionary of your values to your locking mechanism

Comment: Is this a simple example of the real problem? Are you looking at named semaphores because you need inter-process coordination? Are the `res` items inbound requests and unlike the `arr` array the full set and order is not known?

Comment: Don't parallel on arr but on groups in arr.

Comment: ​Related: [Dynamically processing a concurrent collection in parallel by group but serially within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000722/dynamically-processing-a-concurrent-collection-in-parallel-by-group-but-serially).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by grouping the items, and then run the `Parallel.ForEach()` on the groups.

Code (in which I added suffixes to the `B`s so we can distinguish them):

```
string[] arr = ["A", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "C"];
var groups = arr.GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToArray();

var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };

Parallel.ForEach(groups, options, group =>
{
    foreach (var res in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start " + res);
        Thread.Sleep(50 + rnd.Next(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("End   " + res);
    }
});
Thread.Sleep(4500);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/t5wm1a

Output run 1:

```
Start A
Start B1
Start C
End   B1
Start B2
End   C
End   A
End   B2
Start B3
End   B3
Start B4
End   B4
Start B5
End   B5
Done
```

Output run 2:

```
Start C
Start B1
Start A
End   A
End   B1
Start B2
End   C
End   B2
Start B3
End   B3
Start B4
End   B4
Start B5
End   B5
Done
```

The output shows:

- No `B` starts until the previous `B` has ended.
- `A` and `C` run in parallel with all of the `B`s.

---

Update: initially I used `Task.Delay` but `Thread.Sleep` is better in this scenario (see comments below).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware. I added it only so I could do the `await Task.Delay()` to simulate a process that takes time. Not sure what else to use, doing GetAwaiter().GetResult() is usually not good, maybe here it would be OK, and it's just sample code anyway.

Comment:  Thanks, will update the code.

Comment: This is a good solution. One drawback is that the processing order might differ from the order of the items in the `arr`. For example for `arr = ["A1", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "D", "A2"]` the `"A2"` will be processed before the `"D"`.

Comment: You might want to add `if (state.ShouldExitCurrentIteration) break;` inside the `foreach` loop, for more responsive completion in case of an exception. And use the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) overload that has a lambda with `state` parameter: `(group, state) =>`